# Adb shell 192.?????? Why does it come back target is offline

Tags: wireless-networking, android, adb

Tying to connect a Android 10 cellphone to an adroid tablet using termux when I type the command

```bash
adb connect 192.????:22
```

it's says it's connected but my target ip address is offline why is it offline an how can I get it online remotely

Comment: @Ramhound Not all of 192.0.0.0/8. Only 192.168.0.0/16.

Comment: Before you can connect to an Android device via ADB over IP you first have to enable adb tcp mode on the target device. That requires an ADB USB connection or a rooted device. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/150978